# After Insert trigger on ContentDocumentLink runs twice for 1 record. How to prevent the same?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

When iterated over Trigger.new for ContentDocumentLink, I'm trying to filter out some ContentDocumentLink records basis on the entity it is linked to.( Code snippet below. ) The system.debug shows same results but twice after some ms time interval. It is causing my functionality to run twice, how do I prevent the same?

```
if(govAgreementIds !=null){
        for(ContentDocumentLink att:(List<ContentDocumentLink>)Trigger.new){
            if(govAgreementIds.contains(att.LinkedEntityId)){
                finalcdId.add(att.ContentDocumentId);
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug('finalcdId>> '+finalcdId);
```

Debugs logs :
**17:08:07:232** USER_DEBUG [251]|DEBUG|finalcdId>> {0698A000000eg6bQAA}
**17:08:08:528** USER_DEBUG [251]|DEBUG|finalcdId>> {0698A000000eg6bQAA}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard Salesforce behaviour.
This documentation on [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm#!) mentions that triggers can be called twice (update triggers) once before and once after execution of workflow rules if something needs to be updated (see point #4, #8 and #11c)

To work around this for some reason, create a simple boolean class variable (a "flag") and use it to control/avoid the second execution:

```
public class HelperClass {
   public static boolean firstRun = true;  
}
trigger affectedTrigger on Account (before delete, after delete, after undelete) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            if(HelperClass.firstRun){        // check if running for first time
                Trigger.old[0].addError('Before Account Delete Error');
                HelperClass.firstRun=false;      // falsify the flag to denote it has already run before
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source for the code: [Answer #26 from Jitendra's blog](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-interview-questions-part-3/)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Same ContentDocumentId can be shared across multiple LinkedEntityId's. your if condition checking LinkedEntityId. There may be multiple linkentity ID's for same ContentDocumentId. You need to implement code as below

if(govAgreementIds !=null){
        for(ContentDocumentLink att:(List<ContentDocumentLink>)Trigger.new){
            if(govAgreementIds.contains(att.LinkedEntityId)){
              if (!finalcdId.contains(att.ContentDocumentId)) { 
                    finalcdId.add(att.ContentDocumentId);
                   }
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still not working as expected. In the debugs, it is coming twice.